# запутался в типах Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-типы

В вот таком куске кода для простого todo list:

```
 function App() {
  const [newItem, setNewItem] = useState<string>("");
  const [items, setItems] = useState<string[]>([]);

  type itemType = {
    id: number;
    value: string;
  };

  function addItems(): void {
    const item: itemType = {
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000),
      value: newItem,
    };

    setItems(oldList => [...oldList, item]);

    setNewItem("");
  }

  return (
    <div className="todoList">
      <div>
        <h1>Todo list</h1>
        <input
          value={newItem}
          onChange={(e) => setNewItem(e.target.value)}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Add some items..."
        />
        <button onClick={() => addItems()}>add</button>
        <ul>
          {items.map((item) => {
            return <li>{item}</li>;
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Ловлю такую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что такое setItems?

Comment: это обычный useState

Comment: В показанном вами коде нету никакого useState, приведите [mcve] (и версию React на всякий случай)

Comment: всё, уже изменил

Comment: У вас для `items`  задан тип `string[]`, но вы пытаетесь добавить объект.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В стейте items вы объявили дженерик string[], а это значит, что **массив состоит из строк**.

В методе addItem вы пытаетесь в массив строк добавить объект. Измените тип с string[] на itemType[], itemType вынесите в отдельный файл для типов, либо за пределы функции и всё должно заработать должным образом:

```
type itemType = {
    id: number;
    value: string;
};

function App() {
  const [newItem, setNewItem] = useState<string>("");
  const [items, setItems] = useState<itemType[]>([]);

  function addItems(): void {
    const item: itemType = {
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000),
      value: newItem,
    };

    setItems(oldList => [...oldList, item]);

    setNewItem("");
  }

  return (
    <div className="todoList">
      <div>
        <h1>Todo list</h1>
        <input
          value={newItem}
          onChange={(e) => setNewItem(e.target.value)}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Add some items..."
        />
        <button onClick={() => addItems()}>add</button>
        <ul>
          {items.map((item) => {
            return <li>{item}</li>;
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```